# Redis typescript delete method type casting

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis, ioredis

Hello i am wondering which type is right for delete functionality in redis. Code look like this.

```
/**
 * Delete a key
 * - _group_: generic
 * - _complexity_: O(N) where N is the number of keys that will be removed. When a key to remove holds a value other than a string, the individual complexity for this key is O(M) where M is the number of elements in the list, set, sorted set or hash. Removing a single key that holds a string value is O(1).
 * - _since_: 1.0.0
 */
del(...args: [...keys: RedisKey[], callback: Callback<number>]): Result<number, Context>;
del(...args: [keys: RedisKey[], callback: Callback<number>]): Result<number, Context>;
del(...args: [...keys: RedisKey[]]): Result<number, Context>;
del(...args: [keys: RedisKey[]]): Result<number, Context>;
```

So my function looks like this

```
 public async del(key: RedisKey[] | RedisKey) {
    return this._redis.del(key)
  }
```

Here is RedisKey declaration

```
export declare type RedisKey = string | Buffer;
```

For some reason it is not possible to pass string or array of strings at the same time.

Getting this error

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Argument of type '[RedisKey | RedisKey[]]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[...keys: RedisKey[], callback: Callback<number>]'.     Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 1 in target.       Type 'RedisKey | RedisKey[]' is not assignable to type 'Callback<number>'.         Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Callback<number>'.   Overload 2 of 4, '(...args: RedisKey[]): Promise<number>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'RedisKey | RedisKey[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisKey'.       Type 'RedisKey[]' is not assignable to type 'RedisKey'.         Type 'RedisKey[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Buffer': write, toJSON, equals, compare, and 73 more.   Overload 3 of 4, '(keys: RedisKey[]): Promise<number>', gave the following error.     Argument of type 'RedisKey | RedisKey[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RedisKey[]'.       Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RedisKey[]'.
```

[image: error code]

If i put just  **RedisKey[]** or **RedisKey** it works as expected, but it won't work with both types. Please can someone elaborate what to do since there are 4 del() declarations, i am not sure what is going on? Function should accept both types just string or array of strings, so i want delete only one key or multiple keys in redis.

Comment: What redis node module are you using?

Comment: ioredis 4.28 lib in node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process the parameter `key` and make parameters for `redis.del()` to match one of the overload signatures.

```
import Redis, { RedisKey } from 'ioredis';

const redis = new Redis();

async function del(key: RedisKey[] | RedisKey) {
    const keys = Array.isArray(key) ? key : [key];
    return redis.del(keys);
}

del('key'); // ok
del(['key1', 'key2']); //ok
del('key1', 'key2'); // error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYBNgGcA0cDejUYDSSAnnAL5wBmUEIcA5MNAegwNwBQnAxhAHbp4UVnAC8cfkgDu+NOgAUASi6cAhuhL8e1AK7aYzfnBRIANgoDWpAFxyipANoBdOAB976YiSW5OASDMkeGsSdHE4AEEoKDUSADoMaNiSK1JfAH44ULg7R1DnLn8RGF0oYxF5eNMLUPQVTnJuGoUGUIYGlsc20gBGBmwekgAmBmcVIA)

Or

```
import Redis, { RedisKey } from 'ioredis';

const redis = new Redis();

async function del(...args: [...keys: RedisKey[]] | [keys: RedisKey[]]) {
    return redis.del(args.flat());
}

del('key');  // ok
del(['key1', 'key2']); // ok
del('key1', 'key2'); // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYBNgGcA0cDejUYDSSAnnAL5wBmUEIcA5MNAegwNwBQnAxhAHbp4UVnAC8cfkgDu+NOgAUASi6cAhuhL8e1AK7aYzfnBRIANgoB01tVADm6AFxwA2tcsBrUk7lFSLgF0AuAAfVy8SH2R5YhJAgKVcTgBIERhdKGMReUtTC1sHSyozNRhlFU5ybjyFBgiGCpqXOtIARgZsFpIAJgYErhqu9s6I3oqgA)

package version: `"ioredis": "^5.3.2"`

Comment: Tnx sir great!. Please can you explain second way with args.flat(), how it works when you pass string?

Comment: @VladimirŠtus The rest parameter syntax allows a function to accept an indefinite number of arguments as an array, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: yes great tnx once again!